# Vulkan: Loading floating point textures

Tags: textures, vulkan

I am following along the tutorial series here. https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Texture_mapping/Combined_image_sampler the source is here https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/25_texture_mapping.cpp, the tutorial loads in images in the format

```
VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM
```

I am trying to load textures/hdr textures with other formats like,
VK_FORMAT_R16_SFLOAT, VK_FORMAT_R32_SFLOAT, VK_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SFLOAT etc...
making sure that all the format parameters are identical within the texture loading functions.

```
float* pixels = stbi_loadf(file.c_str(), &texWidth, &texHeight, &texChannels, STBI_grey (or STBI_rgb_alpha) in

void createTextureImage(....).
```

But I receive an error which says

```
pRegion[0] exceeds buffer size of 1048576 bytes.. The Vulkan spec states: srcBuffer must be large enough to contain all buffer locations that are accessed according to Buffer and Image Addressing, for each element of pRegions
```

in the void copyBufferToImage(....)

```
void copyBufferToImage(VkBuffer buffer, VkImage image, uint32_t width, uint32_t height) {
    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = beginSingleTimeCommands();

    VkBufferImageCopy region = {};
    region.bufferOffset = 0;
    region.bufferRowLength = 0;
    region.bufferImageHeight = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    region.imageSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
    region.imageOffset = {0, 0, 0};
    region.imageExtent = {
        width,
        height,
        1
    };
    vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(commandBuffer, buffer, image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &region);

    endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
}
```

I can view portions of the floating point image if I reduce the extents in VkBufferImageCopy region = {} and I've tried to issue multiple vkCmdCopyBufferToImage commands to patch together the original texture with region.offset, However in Sacha's examples he doesn't appear to use multiple copy commands to piecemeal the image together to no avail, also I can load in 30mb textures with no problem, making me think that the *pixel data itself is not in the right format. What is the correct approach to loading in floating point data to create a texture?

The complete Texture loading Function:

```
 void createTextureImage() {
    int texWidth, texHeight, texChannels;
    stbi_uc* pixels = stbi_load("textures/texture.jpg", &texWidth, &texHeight, &texChannels, STBI_rgb_alpha);
    VkDeviceSize imageSize = texWidth * texHeight * 4;

    if (!pixels) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to load texture image!");
    }

    VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory stagingBufferMemory;
    createBuffer(imageSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, stagingBuffer, stagingBufferMemory);

    void* data;
    vkMapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, 0, imageSize, 0, &data);
        memcpy(data, pixels, static_cast<size_t>(imageSize));
    vkUnmapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory);

    stbi_image_free(pixels);

    createImage(texWidth, texHeight, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, textureImage, textureImageMemory);

    transitionImageLayout(textureImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL);
        copyBufferToImage(stagingBuffer, textureImage, static_cast<uint32_t>(texWidth), static_cast<uint32_t>(texHeight));
    transitionImageLayout(textureImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL);

    vkDestroyBuffer(device, stagingBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, nullptr);
}

void createTextureImageView() {
    textureImageView = createImageView(textureImage, VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM);
}

void createTextureSampler() {
    VkSamplerCreateInfo samplerInfo = {};
    samplerInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO;
    samplerInfo.magFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    samplerInfo.minFilter = VK_FILTER_LINEAR;
    samplerInfo.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerInfo.addressModeV = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerInfo.addressModeW = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerInfo.anisotropyEnable = VK_TRUE;
    samplerInfo.maxAnisotropy = 16;
    samplerInfo.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_INT_OPAQUE_BLACK;
    samplerInfo.unnormalizedCoordinates = VK_FALSE;
    samplerInfo.compareEnable = VK_FALSE;
    samplerInfo.compareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_ALWAYS;
    samplerInfo.mipmapMode = VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR;

    if (vkCreateSampler(device, &samplerInfo, nullptr, &textureSampler) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create texture sampler!");
    }
}

VkImageView createImageView(VkImage image, VkFormat format) {
    VkImageViewCreateInfo viewInfo = {};
    viewInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
    viewInfo.image = image;
    viewInfo.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
    viewInfo.format = format;
    viewInfo.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    viewInfo.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    viewInfo.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    viewInfo.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    viewInfo.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

    VkImageView imageView;
    if (vkCreateImageView(device, &viewInfo, nullptr, &imageView) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create texture image view!");
    }

    return imageView;
}

void createImage(uint32_t width, uint32_t height, VkFormat format, VkImageTiling tiling, VkImageUsageFlags usage, VkMemoryPropertyFlags properties, VkImage& image, VkDeviceMemory& imageMemory) {
    VkImageCreateInfo imageInfo = {};
    imageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
    imageInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
    imageInfo.extent.width = width;
    imageInfo.extent.height = height;
    imageInfo.extent.depth = 1;
    imageInfo.mipLevels = 1;
    imageInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
    imageInfo.format = format;
    imageInfo.tiling = tiling;
    imageInfo.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
    imageInfo.usage = usage;
    imageInfo.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
    imageInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;

    if (vkCreateImage(device, &imageInfo, nullptr, &image) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create image!");
    }

    VkMemoryRequirements memRequirements;
    vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(device, image, &memRequirements);

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo allocInfo = {};
    allocInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    allocInfo.allocationSize = memRequirements.size;
    allocInfo.memoryTypeIndex = findMemoryType(memRequirements.memoryTypeBits, properties);

    if (vkAllocateMemory(device, &allocInfo, nullptr, &imageMemory) != VK_SUCCESS) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to allocate image memory!");
    }

    vkBindImageMemory(device, image, imageMemory, 0);
}

void transitionImageLayout(VkImage image, VkFormat format, VkImageLayout oldLayout, VkImageLayout newLayout) {
    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = beginSingleTimeCommands();

    VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier = {};
    barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
    barrier.oldLayout = oldLayout;
    barrier.newLayout = newLayout;
    barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
    barrier.image = image;
    barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
    barrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
    barrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    barrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

    VkPipelineStageFlags sourceStage;
    VkPipelineStageFlags destinationStage;

    if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL) {
        barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;

        sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT;
        destinationStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
    } else if (oldLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL && newLayout == VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL) {
        barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT;
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT;

        sourceStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
        destinationStage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
    } else {
        throw std::invalid_argument("unsupported layout transition!");
    }

    vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
        commandBuffer,
        sourceStage, destinationStage,
        0,
        0, nullptr,
        0, nullptr,
        1, &barrier
    );

    endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
}

void copyBufferToImage(VkBuffer buffer, VkImage image, uint32_t width, uint32_t height) {
    VkCommandBuffer commandBuffer = beginSingleTimeCommands();

    VkBufferImageCopy region = {};
    region.bufferOffset = 0;
    region.bufferRowLength = 0;
    region.bufferImageHeight = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
    region.imageSubresource.mipLevel = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.baseArrayLayer = 0;
    region.imageSubresource.layerCount = 1;
    region.imageOffset = {0, 0, 0};
    region.imageExtent = {
        width,
        height,
        1
    };

    vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(commandBuffer, buffer, image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, 1, &region);

    endSingleTimeCommands(commandBuffer);
}
```

Comment: You show us some code that loads data into CPU allocated memory. Then you show us some code that copies data from a Vulkan buffer into a Vulkan image. You're missing the step where you take the CPU allocated memory and copy it into a Vulkan buffer. Which should also include the creation of the buffer and the memory used by that buffer. That is after all what the error message is complaining about.

Comment: I've edited my question to include the entire create image process, the problem occurs when I try any other format other than VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM

Comment: The error says the buffer is too small. You are asking Vulkan to copy from past the end of the buffer. You have hardcoded `VkDeviceSize imageSize = texWidth * texHeight * 4;` therefore Texel Block Size of the chosen format has to be 4 bytes. `VK_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_SFLOAT` would not work with that.

Comment: @krOoze yes I have just stumbled upon that in my code through trial and error  VkDeviceSize imageSize = texWidth * texHeight *sizeof(float) ; now I don't get the buffer is too small error, now I can load the entire image, however I can just see a portion of the image.

Comment: Yay!!! the floating point image was in the 0-1 range therefore I couldn't see the image.  Now with after converting it into 0-255 range I can see the entire image and no errors!!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that my buffer size wasn't large enough for the floating point format.  Now when loading an floating point hdr heightmap texture the image size must be changed to

```
 VkDeviceSize imageSize = texWidth * texHeight *sizeof(float) ;
```

in the createTexture(....) function.

The error was because the staging buffer was not large enough.

```
VkFormat format = VK_FORMAT_R32_SFLOAT;

void  createTextureImage(Texture &texture, std::string file) {
    int texWidth, texHeight, texChannels;
    float* pixels = stbi_loadf(file.c_str(), &texWidth, &texHeight, &texChannels, STBI_grey);
    VkDeviceSize imageSize = texWidth * texHeight ;
    for (int i = 0; i < imageSize; i++)
    {
        pixels[i] *=255; 
    } 

    imageSize = texWidth * texHeight * sizeof(float);
    texture.mipLevels = static_cast<uint32_t>(std::floor(std::log2(std::fmax(texWidth, texHeight)))) + 1;

    texture.width = texWidth;
    texture.height = texHeight;


    if (!pixels) {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to load texture image!");
    }

    VkBuffer stagingBuffer;
    VkDeviceMemory stagingBufferMemory;
    createBuffer(imageSize, VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT, stagingBuffer, stagingBufferMemory);

    void* data;
    vkMapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, 0, imageSize, 0, &data);
    memcpy(data, pixels, static_cast<size_t>(imageSize));
    vkUnmapMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory);

    stbi_image_free(pixels);

    createImage(texWidth, texHeight, texture.mipLevels, format, VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL, VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT, VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT, texture.image, texture.deviceMemory);

    transitionImageLayout(texture.image, format, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL, texture.mipLevels);
    copyBufferToImage(stagingBuffer, texture.image, static_cast<uint32_t>(texWidth), static_cast<uint32_t>(texHeight));
    //transitioned to VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL while generating mipmaps

    vkDestroyBuffer(device, stagingBuffer, nullptr);
    vkFreeMemory(device, stagingBufferMemory, nullptr);

    generateMipmaps(texture.image, format, texWidth, texHeight, texture.mipLevels);
}
```